# Show that a group is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$Let $$ G = \mathrm{Aff}(\R) := \{ f\colon\R\to\R\mid 
  f \colon x\mapsto ax+b, a \in \R^*, b \in \R \} $$
Then $(G,\circ)$ is a group where $\circ$ denotes function composition $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$. Now let 
$$N := \{ f\in G\mid  f\colon x\mapsto x+d, d \in \R \}$$
and 
$$ H := \{ g\in G \mid x \mapsto cx, c \in \R^*\} $$
I have shown that $G$ is a group and that $N$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G$. Now I have to show that $N$ is isomorphic to $\R$ and that $H$ is isomorphic to $\R^*$. After  that I have to show that $G$ is the semidirect product of $N$ by $H$.

I am stuck at showing that they are isomorphic. Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The bijections are implicitly given when the sets $N,H$ were given by formulas: each $f\in N$ corresponds to its determining parameter $d\in\Bbb R$, and each $g\in H$ corresponds to its parameter $c\in\Bbb R^*$. The only thing to prove is that they preserve the given group operation, $+$ in case of $N$ and $\cdot$ in case of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first try to show that $G\simeq N \rtimes H$. I think that's easy to show.
This is not requested but I do believe it's a good exercise.

Now my hint.
To do what you want demonstrate that:
$\forall \tau_d \in N$ such that $\tau_d(x)= x+d$, $\varphi: N  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(\tau_d)= d$ is an isomorphism. 
"Same" thing try to do for $H$.

In this sense $G\simeq \mathbb{R}\rtimes \mathbb{R}^{*}$.

Comment: ok so i have shown that  φ(τd) is an isomorphism for both N and H. Only thing left now is to show that G is a semidirect product of N and H, G≃N⋊H.

Comment: If you want an idea consider:
$\chi: N \rtimes H \rightarrow G$ such that $\chi((a,b))=\tau_{a,b}$, considering that $\tau$ such that $\tau(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's look at the mapping $\theta\colon \mathbb{R} \to N$ defined like this: for every $d \in \mathbb{R}$ set $\theta(d) = f$, where $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\ f(x) = x + d \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. In human words, $\theta$ maps each $d \in \mathbb{R}$ to the function that "shifts" all numbers by $d$.

Can you prove that $\theta$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $N$? That it is an isomorphism?